# Subtracting month values in a table

Tags: vba

I have a 'summary' table, where the first column is the date the values were taken on, and subsequent columns just data. 
I'm trying to make it so that when I press a button, data is entered, but if there is a change in month, a 'total row' (aka just another row that i can set values to) is inserted.

I can't figure out how to do the if statement month check.

Tried googling everything, couldn't really find anything specific to this, only bunch of pieces that i can't figure out how to assemble.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dtbl As ListObject
Dim ss As Worksheet
Dim newrow As ListRow


Set ss = Worksheets("Summary")
Set dtbl = ss.ListObjects("Summary_Table")
Dim last As Long
Dim slast As Long

last = dtbl.Range.Rows.Count
slast = dtbl.Range.Rows.Count - 1

With dtbl
    If Month(.Cells(last, 1)) - Month(.Cells(slast, 1)) = 0 Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add     'need to add above, not below
            With newrow
                .Range(1) = 1 'replace with desired values
                .Range(2) = 2
            End With
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Summary Table:

```
December 5    data1    data2    data3
December 7    data1    data2    data3
...
December 31   data1   data2   data3
TOTAL         SUM(DATA1)   ...   ...
January 3    data1    data2   data3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have your data as an Excel table and create a pivottable of it with month subtotal rows? I would have the date field as an actual date field but format to appear as you want. Also add month and year fields to assist with later grouping. You can use Year and Month functions applied to date field to create these additional columns. Setting up your data properly at the start makes this an easy to maintain format.

[image]

Then just add a button to the sheet associated with code to refresh the pivottable? Or just right click refresh if this is the only action required.

```
Worksheets("SheetName").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotCache.Refresh
```

You could even put inside a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this, must be the eggnog kicking in. Thanks for the suggestion, definitely will help in keep it organized in the future too.